# How to Add SubListBox to my Main ListBox

Tags: windows-10, script, autohotkey, gui, list

I have already develop my ListBox (screenshot attached).

[image]

Listed As:

1. Inquiry_Callback
2. OptOut_Unsub
3. OptOut_Callback
4. Dispute_Callback
5. Others_Others
6. S_Inquiry_Callback
7. S_OptOut_Unsub
8. S_OptOut_Callback
9. S_Dispute_Callback
10. S_Others_Others
11. S_Inquiry_Callback_N
12. S_OptOut_Callback_N
13. S_Dispute_Callback_N
14. Email_Opt_out_IVR
15. S_Email_OptOut_IVR
16. S_Email_OptOut_IVR_N

I have 29 customers which can fall on either one of the above categories, meaning its 16 x 29 = 464 templates.

My question is, how can I modify my listbox so that when I put the cursor on any items (using Up/Down arrows), a new sliding listbox on the right-side will appear for that specific item and listed there are all the 29 customers. Like the ones in word/excel that when you click on File Menu, a submenu will appear, then for every item in the slide menu, there are 2nd level menu appearing with its own items.

Here is the Code of my listbox:

```
Gui, Add, ListBox, gAction vChoise w190 h440 c66ff00, Inquiry_Callback|OptOut_UnSub|OptOut_Callback|Dispute_Callback|Others_Others|-|S_Inquiry_Callback|S_OptOut_Unsub|S_OptOut_Callback|S_Dispute_Callback|S_Others_Others|-|S_Inquiry_Callback_N|S_OptOut_Callback_N|S_Dispute_Callback_N|-|Email_OptOut_IVR|-|S_Email_OptOut_IVR|S_Email_OptOut_IVR_2|-|dummy

return

^F1:: Gui, Show, x400 y180, Actions

Action:

If ((A_GuiEvent = "DoubleClick") || (Trigger_Action))

    Gui, Submit

{

If (Choise = "Inquiry_Callback")

    {

        do this, do that

    }

If (Choise = "OptOut_UnSub")

    {

        do this, do that

    }

If (Choise = "OptOut_Callback")

    {

        do this, do that

    }

If (Choise = "Dispute_Callback")

    {

        do this, do that

    }

If (Choise = "Others_Others")

    {

        do this, do that

    }

If (Choise = "S_Inquiry_Callback")

    {

        do this, do that

    }

If (Choise = "S_OptOut_Unsub")

    {

        do this, do that

    }

If (Choise = "S_OptOut_Callback")

    {

        do this, do that

    }

If (Choise = "S_Dispute_Callback")

    {

        do this, do that

    }

and so on...

If (Choise = "dummy")

        MsgBox, Reserved for Additional Customer

}

return

#If WinActive("Actions ahk_class AutoHotkeyGUI")

    Enter::

        Trigger_Action := true

        GoSub, Action

        Trigger_Action := false

    return

#If

GuiEscape:

Gui, cancel

GuiClose: 

Gui, cancel   

Return
```

Hope u get what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
DetectHiddenWindows, On
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

Gui, Add, ListBox, gAction vChoise w190 h440 c66ff00, Inquiry_Callback||OptOut_UnSub|OptOut_Callback|dummy
return

^F1:: Gui, Show, x400 y180, Actions

Action:
If ((A_GuiEvent = "DoubleClick") || (Trigger_Action))
{
    WinClose, _Actions.ahk - AutoHotkey v ahk_class AutoHotkey
    Gui, Submit, NoHide
    If (Choise = "dummy")
       MsgBox, Reserved for Additional Customer
    else
    {
        IfNotExist, %A_ScriptDir%\%Choise%_Actions.ahk
           GoSub, Create_Choise_Script
        Run, %A_ScriptDir%\%Choise%_Actions.ahk
    }
}
return

Create_Choise_Script:
FileAppend,
(
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

; Gui, -Caption
Gui, Add, ListBox, gCustomerAction vChoise w500 h50, customer1||customer2|customer3
WinGetPos, X, Y, Width,, Actions ahk_class AutoHotkeyGUI
Xn := (X+Width)
Gui, Show, x`%Xn`% y`%Y`%, %Choise%_Actions
return

CustomerAction:
If ((A_GuiEvent = "DoubleClick") || (Trigger_CustomerAction))
{
    WinClose, Actions ahk_class AutoHotkeyGUI  ; after pressing the final choice (the Customer), the ListBox will CLOSE
    Gui, Submit 
    If (Choise = "customer1")
       MsgBox, customer1
    If (Choise = "customer2")
       MsgBox, customer2
    If (Choise = "customer3")
       MsgBox, customer3
     ExitApp
}
return


#If WinActive("%Choise%_Actions ahk_class AutoHotkeyGUI")

    Enter::
        Trigger_CustomerAction := true
        GoSub, CustomerAction
        Trigger_CustomerAction := false
    return

     Left::   ;  go back
         WinActivate, Actions ahk_class AutoHotkeyGUI
         ExitApp
     return

#If

GuiEscape:
GuiClose:
    ExitApp

), %A_ScriptDir%\%Choise%_Actions.ahk
Return


#If WinActive("Actions ahk_class AutoHotkeyGUI")

    Enter::
    Right::
        Trigger_Action := true
        GoSub, Action
        Trigger_Action := false
    return

#If

GuiEscape:
GuiClose: 
    Gui, cancel
Return
```

Comment: Hi, this is nice. Can you pls edit it a bit. For example, when I put the cursor on Inquiry_Callback, then realized that its not what I want, to go back, I need to press ESCAPE to go back to select another (ie: OptOut_Unsub). Can you make it like: {I will press Up/Down to make a choice, then I will press RIGHT to reveal the SubMenu, and press LEFT to go back if I realize I will choose another on the main menu (ie: OptOut_Callback or another)}. Thanks.

Comment: Also, after pressing the final choice (the Customer), the ListBox will CLOSE, and the program will proceed in performing the corresponding action. Because in your given code, when I choose a final option (ie: Customer 1), the ListBox still remains there. Thanks.